# Reading pyqt stylesheet from external qss file

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, stylesheet

I have made a qss file of pyqt stylsheet and how am I supposed to call the file content and feed to `self.setStylesheet(..)`?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
s = QtCore.QString('c:\myProject\darkFantasy.stylesheet')
```

The above code loads the path string rather than the actual stylesheet.

So how do I load the actual content of the stylesheet file?
Should I read it using the open file in read mode?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Figured out the answer:

```
sshFile="darkorange.stylesheet"
with open(sshFile,"r") as fh:
    self.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
```

Comment: You don't need to make it a `QString` and better to close the `fh` or use `with`. I've edited your post.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pyqt And Pyside load stylesheet css file

```
#load file
styleFile = QFile('stylesheet/style.css')
#set file mode 
styleFile.open(QFile.OpenModeFlag.ReadOnly)
#convert QbyteArray to String
convert = styleFile.readAll().toStdString()
#set stylesheet
self.setStyleSheet(convert)
```