# explicitly setting style sheet in python pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

In pyqt standard way for setting style sheet is like this:

```
MainWindow.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("/*\n"
"gridline-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"QToolTip\n"
"{\n"
"    border: 1px solid #76797C;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(90, 102, 117);;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    opacity: 200;\n"
"}\n"
"#label_3{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(90, 102, 117);\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"    padding-left:20px;\n"
" \n"
"}\n"
"#label_2{\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"    padding-left:20px;\n"
" \n"
"}\n"
```

But like we link the stylesheet in html
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`
.can't we do the same in pyqt?It helps in organizing the things.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504421/pyqt-how-to-apply-style-sheet-to-a-custom-widget

Comment: In what way is this duplicate?

Comment: @kragor. I think Laurent was suggesting that you could make things a whole lot simpler if you used triple quotes.

Comment: There is no built-in function in Qt to load an external style sheet. But you can stil do it yourself, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506787/reading-pyqt-stylesheet-from-external-qss-file/14506980).

Comment: Or put all the (triple-quoted) stylesheets in a *styles.py* module and import them as needed.

Comment: thanks for the ideas,but my question was is there any way to explicitly link the style sheet in pyqt4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are currently only two main ways to set a stylesheet. The first is to use the `setStyleSheet` method:

```
widget.setStyleSheet("""
    QToolTip {
        border: 1px solid #76797C;
        background-color: rgb(90, 102, 117);
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        opacity: 200;
    }
    """)
```

This will only take a string, so an external resource would need to be explicitly read from a file, or imported from a module.

The second method is to use the [`-stylesheet` command-line argument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#QApplication), which allows an external qss resource to be specified as a path:

```
python myapp.py -stylesheet style.qss
```

This opens up the possibility of a tempting hack, since it is easy enough to manipulate the args passed to the `QApplication` constructor, and explicitly insert a default stylesheet:

```
import sys

args = list(sys.argv)
args[1:1] = ['-stylesheet', 'style.qss']

app = QtGui.QApplication(args)
```

(Inserting the extra arguments at the beginning of the list ensures that it is still possible for the user to override the default with their own stylesheet).